# What is "Them" related to in this text?

Tags: pronouns, parsing

in the NY times headline I found this:

"Traffic deaths in New York City have risen to the highest level in eight years. A new campaign aims to shock them into slowing down."

what is "Them" related to? "Traffic deaths"? can a campaign shock Traffic deaths? make any sense?

Answer (score 3):

There is a headline, which you did not quote. What you quoted was the subhead or [subheading](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/craft-subheadlines-click).

> **How to Stop Speeding Drivers? Scare Them.**
>
> Traffic deaths in New York City have risen to the highest level in
> eight years. A new campaign aims to shock them into slowing down.

We can use 'them' to refer to things or people already mentioned. Here 'speeding drivers' have already been mentioned, and in view of that is is easy to work out who should 'slow down'.